# AndroidTV app builds ok and will install but can't be opened. Android 7.1.1 TV

Tags: android-tv

I'm at the bottom of the J curve as far as Android development goes, but I can't even get the demo app to work on my Android TV. I build the TV device blank activity in Android Studio, and it works fine in an emulator. I have a banner(320x180pixels), android.hardware.touchscreen(false), android.software.leanback(true), and LEANBACK_LAUNCHER in the intent.

The APK (which I have signed with V2 and marked as a release) installs with warnings from playprotect (which I can't shut off in this locked-down TV) but cannot be opened. I have sideloaded other APK's via the same method. I have also tried not signing the APK.

The TV is an Axis 1832S running Android 7.1.1. I *CAN* put it into developer mode if that helps.

Does anyone have any hints, or a simple 'hello world' apk that works that I can try?

Comment: I'm interested to see what comes of this. I have this issue sometimes when I side-load to my phone. I end up rebuilding and pushing again and it works. No idea what the difference is.

Comment: What happens when you try to launch the app? Are you seeing the banner in the apps list and able to trigger it that way or can you open it via adb?adb shell am start -S -W com.example.app/com.example.app.StartActivity -c android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER -a android.intent.action.MAIN

Comment: I haven't fired up the adb but otherwise it's like the app does not exist at all. It does not appear in the apps list.